# Can't connect to any WiFi, no WiFi network is shown; but WiFi works in recovery mode

Tags: network, wifi

Cannot join any WiFi network. No network is shown. When I click on **Join other networks** and **Show networks**, the list is empty.

When I restart the Mac in Diagnostic Mode, (<kbd>D</kbd> is pressed when starting) then everything is fine, no problems are detected.

When I start the Mac in Recovery Mode (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is pressed when starting) then all the networks are shown, I can connect to a network, network diagnostic is fine, ping works.

From a command line, `airport -s` lists the wifi networks

I can connect to a network with this command `networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 <SSID_OF_NETWORK> <PASSWORD>`